# Migrated Magento to new server; now magento fails after clearing cache

Tags: magento, database-migration

I'm new here, so let me know if I break any protocols.
Also, please note that I am neither a programmer nor a developer, just a merchant who has hacked himself a store using Magento CE 1.7

I've searched this, but haven't found the specific issue replicated elsewhere.

I decided to change hosts, and had my new hosting service move my entire account to their servers. They created a backup of my account, then restored it on their servers.
Got the SSL installed, and all seemed to be functioning well on the front end, including secure cart pages & customer account pages, etc.

Until I logged into the backend admin of Magento & cleared the cache.

I was presented with an unstyled, tree-like html page of the admin area. I refreshed the screen and got the error: "There has been an error processing your request." followed by the error number. That error screen now also appears when browsing the front end of my site.

I notified my new host, who restored the public_html folder, which brought the site back to life, until I again attempted to clear magento cache. Same errors, same symptoms.

The site worked fine at my previous host ... obviously something happened in the migration. I would expect (but I could be very wrong) the files to have been duplicated precisely in the backup/restore procedure.

I have seen some solutions mentioned here (& elsewhere) that come close to being my problem, but not precisely. So I figured I'd go ahead & ask in hopes that someone has seen this behavior specifically.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

And again, please bear in mind I'm way out of my league so if I ask something nooby, it's because I am, well, very much a newbie!

Oh, sorry, the error is:

```
 a:5:{i:0;s:20:"Invalid URI supplied";i:1;s:1004:"#0 /home/user/public_html/knightowlsurvivalstore.com/lib/Zend/Uri.php(143): Zend_Uri_Http->__construct('http', '//knightowlsurv...')

#1 /home/user/public_html/knightowlsurvivalstore.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(726): Zend_Uri::factory('http://knightow...')

#2 /home/user/public_html/knightowlsurvivalstore.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(313): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()

#3 /home/user/public_html/knightowlsurvivalstore.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

#4 /home/user/public_html/knightowlsurvivalstore.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

#5 /home/user/public_html/knightowlsurvivalstore.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

#6 /home/user/public_html/knightowlsurvivalstore.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

==
[edit: I replaced myusername with 'user' ... ]

Thanks very much in advance!!
Markz

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link

How to change or restore base_url settings with phpMyAdmin

Symptom: I changed Base Urls and now my website is inaccessible or I moved everything to a new server, didn't change the base_url and my website is inaccessible.

Solution: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/restore_base_url_settings

Thanks

Comment: Thank you kindly for your quick response. This will be my first venture into the wonderful world of phpMyAdmin! (I warned ya, I'm a noob!). Inasmuch as I have only one current Magento install, I see 5 magento dbs and one phpn; is there a quick way for me to know which one I should be working on? (I had a couple other magento attempts in the same account, in the past, so that may be where they came from).  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the silly query ... I believe I did indeed find the correct DB. Followed the instructions, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your base url seems wrong. Try setting you base secure and unsecure url from table 'core_config_data'
Search for 'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url'
Please correct this and remove everything from var/cache folder and check

Comment: Hi David: I'm curious what seems wrong with the base url in the errors above? And, I did set base secure & unsecure in the php table. The secure was set to http:// so I changed to https://, then emptied var/cache folder and it still is broken. I'll keep pluggin'. Thanks for your input! markz